# Headless viewer - hiding bottom UI

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Other than to add a css rule for the toolbar to be: `visibility: hidden;`, how can I hide the default viewer UI?

[image]

I saw [this](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/headless/) but I couldn't find what makes the bottom UI hidden.

Comment: Not quite sure about your question, please check the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517648/zoomwindow-extension-breaks-without-gui/42527871#42527871 about setting the toolbar invisible. But if you do not want any UI, just use the headless viewer, this will not show any UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "headless" viewer if you don't want any UI at all:

`var viewer = new Viewer3D(domContainer)`

But I don't see what's wrong with setting the css, it's a dom element, so any API you use would ultimately impact the css ...